# How do I change the color of an object with getElementById("").style.color in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid, event-listener

I'm trying to change the color of the box to blue when the button2 (named "blue") is clicked.

This is the code which isn't working.... Could anyone help plz?

### The DEMO

```js
  document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
     document.getElementById("box").style.height = "300px";
     document.getElementById("box").style.width = "300px";
  });


document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){

    document.getElementById("box").style.color = 'blue';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript.js"></script>

        

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the background color instead of color property of HTML element.

```
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){    
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
```

Please find working snippit below:

```js
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){    
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfect now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you use wrong attribute change color to background instead

```
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

<button id="button0">Grow</button>

<button onclick="Grow()" id="button1">Grow</button>
<button onclick="Blue()" id="button2">Blue</button>
<button onclick="Fade()" id="button3">Fade</button>
<button onclick="Reset()" id="button4">Reset</button>
```

```
const box = document.getElementById('box');

document.getElementById('button0').addEventListener('click', e => {
    box.style.width = '500px';
    box.style.height = '500px';
})

const Grow = e => {
    box.style.width = '300px';
    box.style.height = '300px';
}

const Blue = e => {
    box.style.background = 'blue';
}
const Reset = e => {
    box.setAttribute('style', 'height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px');
}
```